# Need to correct for multiple comparisons in SPSS GLM Multivariate Analysis

Tags: multivariate-analysis, spss, multiple-comparisons

Dataset contains:
-8 dependent variables (not repeated measures, all scaled)
-2 independent variables (nominal: 2 levels, ordinal: 3 levels)

IBM alludes to a very simple "just run a post-hoc" solution [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21476685) however, being that my categorical IV only has two levels, SPSS won't perform a post-hoc. 
I would like to report overall p-values for my DVs (example: IV1 did have a significant main effect on DV1, p = 0.001, IV2 did not have a significant main effect on DV1, p = 0.10).

Should I take the p-values from the Tests of Between-Subjects Effects and manually perform a Bonferroni correction? (p-value reported / 8)